# How can I get the length of all arguments given to a function in bash?

Tags: bash, function, arguments, string-length

I'd like to get the length of the string that I get when i use `"$*"` in my function.

I tried:

```
echo ${#"$*"}
```

and

```
echo ${#"*"}
```

both gave me a bad substitution error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it in a single command. However, this seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
a="$@"
echo "${#a}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a temporary variable is <strike>the only</strike> one basic way, and you need to unset IFS or set it to empty string to prevent spaces in between. And use $* not $@ for it would give you spaces in between:

```
IFS= eval "__=\"\$*\""
echo "${#__}"
```

Another way is to loop through all strings:

```
L=0; for __; do (( L += ${#__} )); done
echo "$L"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following.

```
expr length "$*"
echo "$*" | awk '{print length}'
```

Answer (score 0):

$# holds the number of positional parameters passed to the function.

Try it:

```
#!/bin/bash

t() {
  echo "num args=$#"
  echo "all $*"
}

t "$@"
```